# How to grab data from local folders/files on PHP and create JSON data

Tags: php, json, foreach

I would like to output the jason data which looks like a jasondata below on PHP. `folder` is the name of the folder, and `title` is located at the firstline of `info.txt`. `info.txt` is located under the folder. There are three lines in each `info.txt`, and those lines are separated just by making new lines (not commas). folder `books`, and my `php` file is located under the same folder. How can I write a PHP code? Thanks.
MY PHP code is here;

```
function books(){

    $array = [];
    $story = glob("books/" . "*");

    foreach($story as $each){
        $title = file($each ."/info/txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $output = array (
            "title" => $title[0],
            "folder" => $each #i would like to put the name of the folder here
            );
        array_push($array,$review);
    }
    print(json_encode($array));
}
```

Json data should look like;

```
{
    "books" : [
        {
         "title": "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
         "folder": "harrypotter"
         },
        {
         "title": "The Hobbit",
         "folder": "hobbit"
         },
        ... (one entry like this for each folder inside books/)
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DirectoryIterator or scandir functions ,try this code bellow

```
$dirs   = '/directory/';
$dir    = new DirectoryIterator($dirs);
$array  = array();
foreach ($dir as $key => $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        //remove hidden files or dot files
        if ( $fileinfo->getBasename() === '.' || $fileinfo->getBasename() === '..' ) continue);

        //foldername 
        $array[$key]['folder'] = $fileinfo->getBasename();

        //title 
        $array[$key]['title'] = file($array[$key]['folder'].'/info.txt' ,  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

let me know if it's worked or not.

**edited** 
I try in my localhost and it's worked

```
$dirs   = 'books/';
$dir    = new DirectoryIterator($dirs);
$array  = array();
foreach ($dir as $key => $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        //remove hidden files or dot files
        if ( $fileinfo->getBasename() === '.' || $fileinfo->getBasename() === '..' ) continue;

        //foldername 
        $array[$key]['folder'] = $fileinfo->getBasename();

        //title 
        $array[$key]['title'] = file($dirs.'/'.$array[$key]['folder'].'/info.txt' ,  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($array);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($json, true).'</pre>';
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I copied your code and changed 'directory' to 'books/', but i did not work... The output said "failed to open stream"...

Comment: is your php file the same folder / directory with books? try to find the right path for your books folder.

Comment: Also I think I dont need ) after 'continue'

Comment: yes, the php file and the 'books' folder are under the same folder

Comment: I'm sorry for miss typo

Comment: I adjusted a little, and it worked somehow now, but $array[$key]['title'] = file($array[$key]['folder'].'/info.txt' ,  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); returns all the lines in info.txt. How could I get only the first line??